# Erro ao gerar classe c# a partir de um XSD

Tags: c#, xsd, visual-studio-2010

Galera, estou tendo que mudar a versão do XSD da minha aplicação, pois a ANS agora flexibilizou o envio do SIB para o SIB FLEX.

Link do XSD: http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/sib/schemas/sib.xsd

Com isso, eu tenho que gerar uma nova classe c# em cima desse novo XSD que citei acima. Só que eu não estou conseguindo gerar a classe, pois, esses erros são apresentados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok... Mas como sou um pouco iniciante na programação eu gostaria de saber.

1 - A declaração desses tipos é feita na classe gerada a partir desse XSD?

2 - Se sim, como vou resolver esse problema se não consigo gerar a classe?

3 - Se não, como declaro esses tipos que constam nesses erros?

4 - Como resolver essa situação?

Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que se consegue perceber do `XSD`, existem dois ficheiros que estão incluídos no *schema*:

```
<!-- Inclusão do arquivo simpleType-->
<xsd:include schemaLocation="sibSimpleType.xsd"/>
<!-- -->
<!-- Inclusão do arquivo complexType-->
<xsd:include schemaLocation="sibComplexType.xsd"/>
```

De forma a gerar a classe correspondente ao ficheiro `sib.xsd` é necessário que tenha, para além do `XSD` "principal", os `XSD` correspondentes aos tipos que estão em falta nesse (os indicados acima), ou seja:

[sibSimpleType.xsd](http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/sib/schemas/sibSimpleType.xsd)
[sibComplexType.xsd](http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/sib/schemas/sibComplexType.xsd)

Com esses dois `XSD` "auxiliares" já conseguirá gerar a classe corretamente:

```
xsd sib.xsd /classes
```

Esse comando irá gerar a classe na pasta onde o estiver a executar.

De salientar que necessita ter **permissões de escrita** na pasta, caso contrário terá erro de acesso.

Comment: Deu certo meu amigo... Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: De nada! Dê um UP e marque a resposta como correta :)